# How do I Store an Image in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'foto_makanan' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->input('foto_makanan')->extension();  
    $request->input('foto_makanan')->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

    $food = new Food();
    $food->nama_makanan = $request->input('nama_makanan');
    $food->foto_makanan = $request->input('foto_makanan');
    $food->harga = $request->input('harga');
    $food->deskripsi = $request->input('deskripsi');
    $food->stok = $request->input('stok');
    $food->category_id = $request->input('flexRadioDefault');
    $food->slug_food =  ucwords(str_replace(" ", "-", $request->input('nama_makanan')));
    $food->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully Add Products!');
}
```

I need to upload an image to public/images folder, please help me
that is my controller code

Comment: ```$request->file('foto_makanan')->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg')```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Comment: it doesnt work.

Comment: Then you haven't provided enough information. You haven't provided how the request is made, there is none of the code from your form, you haven't provided any errors you are getting etc

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add this attribute to form: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Validation of image in this way:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
   'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
]);
```

If you want to get image name:

```
$name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

And upload on `public/images` folder:

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
```

In `$path` variable will be saved path of image